# qooxdoo tabview steals focus

Tags: focus, qooxdoo, tabview

look this [playground example](http://www.qooxdoo.org/current/playground/#%7B%22code%22%3A%22var%2520field%2520%253D%2520new%2520qx.ui.form.TextField()%253B%250Afield.setLiveUpdate(true)%253B%250Avar%2520tabs%2520%253D%2520new%2520qx.ui.tabview.TabView(%2522left%2522)%253B%250A%250Athis.getRoot().add(field)%253B%250A%250Athis.getRoot().add(tabs%252C%2520%257Bleft%2520%253A%2520300%257D)%253B%250A%250Afield.addListener(%2522changeValue%2522%252C%2520function()%2520%257B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520var%2520t%2520%253D%2520qx.lang.Array.clone(tabs.getChildren())%253B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520if%2520(t)%2520%257B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520t.forEach(function(obj)%2520%257B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520tabs.remove(obj)%253B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%257D)%253B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%257D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520tabs.add(new%2520qx.ui.tabview.Page(Math.random().toString(36).substring(2%252C%25205)))%253B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520tabs.add(new%2520qx.ui.tabview.Page(Math.random().toString(36).substring(2%252C%25205)))%253B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520tabs.add(new%2520qx.ui.tabview.Page(Math.random().toString(36).substring(2%252C%25205)))%253B%250A%250A%257D)%253B%22%2C%20%22mode%22%3A%22ria%22%7D)

When tabs are re-created, it steals focus to the text field. Is it a relevant behavior ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug caused by the tabview's current tab being changed programmatically.  It's fixed in this PR https://github.com/qooxdoo/qooxdoo/pull/9117